# ubuntu 18.04 broken on kde font package installation

Tags: upgrade, kde, plasma

```
sudo aptitude install apt-transport-https ca-certificates
ca-certificates is already installed at the requested version (20190110~18.04.1)
ca-certificates is already installed at the requested version (20190110~18.04.1)
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt{a} apt-transport-https gpgv{ab} openssl{ab} 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  banshee:amd64{u} banshee-extension-soundmenu:amd64{u} binutils-mingw-w64-i686:amd64{u} binutils-mingw-w64-x86-64:amd64{u} cabextract:amd64{u} compiz-gnome:amd64{u} dirdiff:amd64{u} djvulibre-bin:amd64{u} fcitx-config-gtk:amd64{u} fcitx-frontend-qt4:amd64{u} 
  firmware-manager-notify:amd64{u} g++-mingw-w64-i686:amd64{u} g++-mingw-w64-x86-64:amd64{u} gcc-mingw-w64-base:amd64{u} gcc-mingw-w64-i686:amd64{u} gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64:amd64{u} gir1.2-goocanvas-2.0:amd64{u} gputils:amd64{u} gtk2-engines-xfce:amd64{u} 
  keepassx:amd64{u} libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl:amd64{u} libaugeas0:amd64{u} libb-hooks-op-check-perl:amd64{u} libbit-vector-perl:amd64{u} libclass-c3-xs-perl:amd64{u} libclass-xsaccessor-perl:amd64{u} libcrypt-blowfish-perl:amd64{u} libcrypt-rijndael-perl:amd64{u} 
  libcwidget3v5:amd64{u} libdate-calc-xs-perl:amd64{u} libdevel-callchecker-perl:amd64{u} libdevel-caller-perl:amd64{u} libdevel-lexalias-perl:amd64{u} libevent-core-2.1-6:amd64{u} libfilesys-df-perl:amd64{u} libgdiplus:amd64{u} libgoocanvas-2.0-9:amd64{u} 
  libgraphicsmagick++-q16-12:amd64{u} libgraphicsmagick-q16-3:amd64{u} libgtk3-nocsd0:amd64{u} libimage-magick-q16-perl:amd64{u} libimage-sane-perl:amd64{u} liblept5:amd64{u} libltdl-dev:amd64{u} libmspack0:amd64{u} libnet-arp-perl:amd64{u} libnet-pcap-perl:amd64{u} 
  libonig4:amd64{u} libossp-uuid-perl:amd64{u} libossp-uuid16:amd64{u} libpackage-stash-xs-perl:amd64{u} libpadwalker-perl:amd64{u} libpango1.0-0:amd64{u} libpangox-1.0-0:amd64{u} libparams-classify-perl:amd64{u} libparams-util-perl:amd64{u} 
  libparams-validate-perl:amd64{u} libproc-processtable-perl:amd64{u} libpython-all-dev:amd64{u} libqtassistantclient4:amd64{u} libref-util-xs-perl:amd64{u} libserf-1-1:amd64{u} libsort-key-perl:amd64{u} libssl1.0-dev:amd64{u} libsub-identify-perl:amd64{u} 
  libsvn1:amd64{u} libtcl8.5:amd64{u} libtesseract4:amd64{u} libtiff-tools:amd64{u} libtk8.5:amd64{u} libunicode-utf8-perl:amd64{u} libuv1-dev:amd64{u} libvariable-magic-perl:amd64{u} libwxbase3.0-0v5:amd64{u} libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5:amd64{u} 
  libx11-guitest-perl:amd64{u} lockfile-progs:amd64{u} mysql-client-5.7:amd64{u} mysql-server-5.7:amd64{u} nodejs-dev:amd64{u} pdf2djvu:amd64{u} pepperflashplugin-nonfree:amd64{u} php7.4-bz2:amd64{u} php7.4-common:amd64{u} php7.4-curl:amd64{u} php7.4-gd:amd64{u} 
  php7.4-mbstring:amd64{u} php7.4-xml:amd64{u} php7.4-zip:amd64{u} presage:amd64{u} procmail:amd64{u} python-all:amd64{u} python-all-dev:amd64{u} python-apt:amd64{u} python-cffi-backend:amd64{u} python-cryptography:amd64{u} python-libxml2:amd64{u} python-pam:amd64{u} 
  python-pil:amd64{u} python-qt4:amd64{u} python-sip:amd64{u} python-twisted-bin:amd64{u} python-wxgtk3.0:amd64{u} python-xapian:amd64{u} python-zope.interface:amd64{u} python3-brlapi:amd64{u} python3-cffi-backend:amd64{u} python3-crypto:amd64{u} 
  python3-cryptography:amd64{u} python3-gpg:amd64{u} python3-icu:amd64{u} python3-nacl:amd64{u} python3-protobuf:amd64{u} python3-renderpm:amd64{u} python3-simplejson:amd64{u} python3-systemd:amd64{u} python3-xapian:amd64{u} python3-yaml:amd64{u} 
  python3-zope.hookable:amd64{u} python3-zope.interface:amd64{u} rmlint:amd64{u} sane:amd64{u} sensible-mda:amd64{u} subversion:amd64{u} tesseract-ocr:amd64{u} tk8.5:amd64{u} 
0 packages upgraded, 4 newly installed, 126 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
After unpacking 795 MB will be freed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 node-delayed-stream : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 libpackage-stash-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 ca-certificates-java : Depends: openjdk-11-jre-headless but it is not going to be installed or
                                 java8-runtime-headless which is a virtual package, provided by:
                                 - ibm-java80-jre (8.0.6.5-0ubuntu1), but it is not going to be installed
                                 - openjdk-8-jre-headless (8u252-b09-1~18.04), but it is not going to be installed
                                 - openjdk-11-jre-headless (11.0.8+10-0ubuntu1~18.04.1), but it is not going to be installed
                                 - default-jre-headless (2:1.11-68ubuntu1~18.04.1), but it is not going to be installed
                                 - openjdk-8-jre-headless (8u162-b12-1), but it is not going to be installed
                                 - openjdk-11-jre-headless (10.0.1+10-3ubuntu1), but it is not going to be installed
                                 - default-jre-headless (2:1.10-63ubuntu1~02), but it is not going to be installed

                        Depends: libnss3 (>= 3.12.9+ckbi-1.82-0ubuntu3~) but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-settings : Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend but it is not going to be installed or
                            gsettings-backend which is a virtual package, provided by:
                            - dconf-gsettings-backend (0.26.0-2ubuntu3), but it is not going to be installed

                   Depends: libglib2.0-bin (>= 2.53.4-3ubuntu1~) but it is not going to be installed
 debconf : PreDepends: perl-base (>= 5.20.1-3~) but it is not going to be installed
 liblog-log4perl-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 python3-pexpect : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) which is a virtual package, provided by:
                            - python3 (3.6.7-1~18.04), but it is not going to be installed
                            - python3 (3.6.5-3), but it is not going to be installed

 postgresql-common : Depends: procps but it is not going to be installed
 evince:amd64 : Depends: evince-common:amd64 (< 3.29) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

                Depends: evince-common:amd64 (>= 3.28) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

 alsa-base : Depends: kmod (>= 17-1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: udev but it is not going to be installed
 python-six : Depends: python:any (< 2.8) which is a virtual package, provided by:
                       - python (2.7.15~rc1-1), but it is not going to be installed

              Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~) which is a virtual package, provided by:
                       - python (2.7.15~rc1-1), but it is not going to be installed

 lxde-core : Depends: lxpanel but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: pcmanfm but it is not going to be installed
 libgit-wrapper-perl : Depends: git but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 libhttp-daemon-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 init-system-helpers : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.20.1-3) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-defer : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) which is a virtual package, provided by:
                          - python3 (3.6.7-1~18.04), but it is not going to be installed
                          - python3 (3.6.5-3), but it is not going to be installed

 gnome-control-center-data : Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend but it is not going to be installed or
                                      gsettings-backend which is a virtual package, provided by:
                                      - dconf-gsettings-backend (0.26.0-2ubuntu3), but it is not going to be installed

 python3-distro-info : Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) which is a virtual package, provided by:
                                - python3 (3.6.7-1~18.04), but it is not going to be installed
                                - python3 (3.6.5-3), but it is not going to be installed

 evolution-data-server-common : Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend but it is not going to be installed or
                                         gsettings-backend which is a virtual package, provided by:
                                         - dconf-gsettings-backend (0.26.0-2ubuntu3), but it is not going to be installed

 inxi : Depends: gawk but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: pciutils but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: procps but it is not going to be installed
 gnome-power-manager:amd64 : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-schemas:amd64 (>= 3.2) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

 tex-common : PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1) but it is not going to be installed
 hplip-data : Depends: xz-utils but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) which is a virtual package, provided by:
                       - python3 (3.6.7-1~18.04), but it is not going to be installed
                       - python3 (3.6.5-3), but it is not going to be installed

 xserver-xorg:amd64 : Depends: python3-apport:amd64 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

 libhttp-message-perl : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
 node-minimatch : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
 python-tdb:amd64 : Depends: python:any (< 2.8) which is a virtual package, provided by:
                             - python (2.7.15~rc1-1), but it is not going to be installed
```

---

lot of packages not visible
help me how to recover

Comment: Start with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall apt` and then run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to get newest dependencies.

Comment: even apt-get is lost..i reinstalled everything from scratch